# Enable/Disable Windows service using batch file

Tags: windows-services

Is there any way to enable and disable a windows service using batch files.
I am talking of changing the startup type of the services i.e. enabling and disabling and not starting and stopping using Net Start and Net Stop commands.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
sc config <service_name> start= disabled
```

This command has a number of functions but one is to determine the status of a service at system startup. A service can be set to run automatically, manually or not at all. The commands are

```
sc config ServiceName start= flag
```

Here ServiceName is the name of the service and flag has one of the values auto, demand. or disabled . For example, to set a service to run manually the command is

```
sc config ServiceName start= demand
```

Note that there must be a space after the equals sign. The correct value for the parameter ServiceName may not always be obvious and the next command can be used to find it for all services.

Answer (score 5):

```
sc config <service_name> start= disabled
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer and a question.
I have put together this single line to disable services that are running

```
sc query "wsearch"| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && net stop "wsearch" && sc config "wsearch" start= disabled
```

This will check the service before attempting to disable and stop. Some I like to change to manual.

Can someone help me put this snippet into a loop

```
for loop sc query "wsearch"| find "RUNNING" >nul 2>&1 && net stop "wsearch" && sc config "wsearch" start= disabled
```

servicename1
  servicename2
  servicename3
endif.....

This way I can make a segment and enter all the service I want to change the status in one single file.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc \\servername config <service_name> Start= auto >> c:\temp\sc.txt
```

changes the start type of the service and logs the output in `c:\temp\sc.txt`.

```
sc \\servername start <service_name>  >> c:\temp\sc1.txt
```

starts the service and logs the output in `c:\temp\sc.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I knot this is a bit late, but for anyone who might run across this in the future, this is a small application snippet i wrote with a DB backend, build the array, loop through it and send the

```
   For SrvLoop As Integer = 0 To UBound(SrverName) - 1
        services = ServiceController.GetServices(SrverName(SrvLoop))
        For Each ChkLV In myobj.Items
            Srv = ChkLV.SubItems(3).Text
            i = ChkLV.SubItems(0).Text
            If ChkLV.Selected = True And Srv = SrverName(SrvLoop) Then
                Select Case Command
                    Case 1
                        If services(i).Status <> ServiceControllerStatus.Running Then
                            services(i).Start()
                        Else
                            MsgBox("Cannot Start a Service that is already Running", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                        End If
                    Case 2
                        'If services(i).CanStop Then
                        If services(i).Status <> ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
                            services(i).Stop()
                            'Else
                            '    If services(i).Status <> ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
                            '        MsgBox("Service not able to be stopped currently" & vbCrLf & "Please try again in a few seconds", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                            '    End If
                        End If
                End Select
                Progress.PB_Progress_Bar.Value += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Progress.Dispose()
```